# Docker TICK Sandbox does not provide UDF Python functionality

Tags: docker, influxdb, kapacitor

I'm running [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/kapacitor/) docker image to use the TICK Kapacitor locally.

The problem I face is that when I try to use User Defined Functions, e.g any of [these examples](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/tree/master/udf/agent/examples) I get the error message that /usr/bin/python2 does not exist.

I add the following to the `kapacitor.conf`:

```
[udf.functions]
[udf.functions.tTest]
    prog = "/usr/bin/python2"
    args = ["-u", "/tmp/kapacitor_udf/mirror.py"]
    timeout = "10s"
    [udf.functions.tTest.env]
        PYTHONPATH = "/tmp/kapacitor_udf/kapacitor/udf/agent/py"
```

Further attempts from my side including altering the image used to build Kapacitor to install python works but the agent seems to fail to compile anyway.

Is there anyone who managed to get UDFs running using the Kapacitor Docker image?

Thanks

Comment: You need to install python for this to work. Also double check your paths both for `args` and `PYTHONPATH` that they have the expected files. mirror in particular depends on protobuf so you need to install that too. I noticed your comment that you installed python and had some problems afterwards, but you do not say what the problems are, which makes it a guessing game.

Comment: I edited my question to add the log. I realised that I need to install python but it seemed a bit odd that the official Kapacitor Docker image does not provide the tools necessary to develop User Defined Functions. It also never mentioned something like this in any documentation which led me to believe the error was on my side.

Answer (score 2):

Docker image from the official repository: `docker pull kapacitor` does not have python installed inside. You can verify this by running shell in the container:

```
PS> docker exec -it kapacitor bash
```

and execute one of the command options:

```
$ python -VERSION 
$ python: command not found
```

or

```
$ readlink -f $(which python) | xargs -I% sh -c 'echo -n "%:"; % -V'
$ readlink: missing operand
```

or

```
$ find / -type f -executable -iname 'python *'
```

void returns. And oppositely if python is available, commands return version and list of executable files

> Note: Here and further all command snippets are given for `Powershell` on Windows. And all command snippets inside docker container are given for `bash` shell as Linux images are used.

---

Basicly, there is two options to get kapacitor image with python inside to execute UDFs:

1. Install the python in the `kapacitor` image, i.e. build new docker image from very `kapacitor` image.
   Example could be found [here](https://github.com/srinivasrk/influx-kapacitor-udf-files/blob/master/Dockerfile):
2. Build a new verion of `kapacitor` image from one of the python official images

   The second option is more natural as you get consistent python installation and keep efforts on doing work of installing python which already done by the docker community.

So following option 2 we'll perform:

1. Examine the Dockefile of the official `kapacitor` image
2. Choose an appropriate python image
3. Create new project and Dockerfile for kapacitor
4. Build and Check the kapacitor image

---

### Examine Dockefile of official kapacitor image

General note:

> For any image, the original Dockerfiles can be obtained in this way:
>
> https://hub.docker.com/ 
>   -> *Description Tab*
>   -> *Supported tags and respective Dockerfile links* section
>   -> each of the *tags is a link that leads to the Dockerfile*

---

So for kapacitor everything is in the [influxdata-docker git repository](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker/tree/master/kapacitor/)

Then in the `Dockerfile` we find that the image is created based on

```
FROM buildpack-deps: stretch-curl
```

here:

> *buildpack-deps*
>
> the image provided by the project of the same name https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps
>
> *curl*
>
> This variant includes just the curl, wget, and ca-certificates packages. This is perfect for cases like the Java JRE, where downloading JARs is very common and
>         necessary, but checking out code isn't.
>
> *stretch*
>
> short version name of the OS, in this case Debian 9 stretch https://www.debian.org/News/2017/20170617

`Buildpack-deps` images are in turn built based on

```
FROM debian: stretch
```

And [Debian images](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian) from the minimum docker image

```
FROM: scratch
```

---

### Choose appropriate python image

Among python images, for example `3.7`, you [can find similar versions inheriting from `buildpack-deps`](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/695bd3c10cdf1692a2af9abdc51f0eff99731e78/3.7/stretch/Dockerfile)

```
FROM buildpack-deps: stretch
```

Following the inheritance, we'll see:

```
FROM buildpack-deps: stretch
FROM buildpack-deps: stretch-smc
FROM buildpack-deps: stretch-curl
FROM debian: stretch
```

In other words, the `python: 3.7-stretch` image only adds functionality to the Debian compared to the `kapacitor` image.
This means that we can to rebuild `kapacitor` image on top of the `python image: 3.7-stretch` with no risk or gaining incompatibility.

---

### Docker context folder preparation

1. Clone the repository
   https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker.git
2. Create the folder `influxdata-docker/kapacitor/1.5/udf_python/python3.7`
3. Copy the following three files into it from `influxdata-docker/kapacitor/1.5/`:

   Dockerfile
   entrypoint.sh
   kapacitor.conf
4. In the copied Dockerfile `FROM buildpack-deps: stretch-curl` replace with `FROM python: 3.7-stretch`
5. **Be carefuly!** If we work on Windows and because of scientific curiosity open the `entrypoint.sh` file in the project folder, then be sure to check that it does not change the end-line character from Linux (`LF`) to Windows variant: (`CR LF`).
      Otherwise, when you start the container later, you get an error:

   - or in the container log:

     ```
     exec: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
     ```
   - or if you'll start debugging and, running the container with bash, will do:

     ```
     $ root @ d4022ac550d4: / # exec /entrypoint_.sh
     $ bash: /entrypoint_.sh: / bin / bash ^ M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
     ```

---

### Building

Run `PS> docker build -f. \ Dockerfile -t kapacitor_python_udf`

> Again, in case of Windows environment
>
> If during the build execution an error occurs of the form:
>
> ```
>   E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 9h 14min 10s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
> ```
>
> then your computer clock probably went out of sync and/or Docker Desktop incorrectly initialized the time after the system returned from sleep. See [the issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4526))
>
> To fix it, restart Docker Desktop and / or Windows settings -> Date and time settings -> Clock synchronization -> perform Sync
>
> You can also read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059217/getting-release-is-not-valid-yet-while-updating-ubuntu-d)

---

### Launch and check

Launching the container with the same actions as for the standard image. Example:

```
PS> docker run --name=kapacitor -d `
    --net=influxdb-network `
    -h kapacitor `
    -p 9092:9092 `
    -e KAPACITOR_INFLUXDB_0_URLS_0=http://influxdb:8086 `
    -v ${PWD}:/var/lib/kapacitor `
    -v ${PWD}/kapacitor.conf:/etc/kapacitor/kapacitor.conf:ro `
kapacitor
```

Check:

```
PS> docker exec -it kapacitor_2 bash

$ python -VERSION
$ Python 3.7.7

$ readlink -f $(which python) | xargs -I% sh -c 'echo -n "%:"; % -V'
$ /usr/local/bin/python3.7: Python 3.7.7
```